# Ubuntu 16.04 - on load WiFi works, when opening browser it stops for 5 minutes and then works again

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, realtek

I have some very weird behavior of Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire F15 laptop, which **happens only when connected to one WiFi network** (on others it works perfectly fine).

## Update 01.07.2017

Most probably this is an issue with the browsers.

Today I had a call on fb messenger. While the call was active, I have opened Mozilla (while working in Chromium) and suddenly, I couldn't load any page in either of them, but the call was going on without interruption. (Also, the dropbox icon indicator shows that it is connected to the internet).

I have tested it later, while having Chromium working, on opening of Mozilla, I could not load any page again, on neither browsers. What could be the problem here?

## Behavior description

Right on startup of Ubuntu, internet works:

```
❯ ping -c5 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.16.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=44.9 ms
64 bytes from fra16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=174 ms
64 bytes from fra16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=42.1 ms
64 bytes from fra16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=178 ms
64 bytes from fra16s08-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.16.206): icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=194 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 42.181/126.757/194.098/68.261 ms
```

But right after I start Chromium (or Firefox), internet doesn't work:

```
❯ ping -c5 google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

**However, if I leave it for 3-5 minutes, it starts working again.** Sometimes, it may work until I shut down my laptop, but occasionally it might stop again for 3-5 minutes and the resume working.

## Hardware and software settings

### `lshw -c network` output

```
❯ sudo lshw -c network                                             
[sudo] password for iulian: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: cc:b0:da:71:b0:73
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.8.0-58-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.0.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:b4000000-b41fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: enp4s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 54:ab:3a:d5:2d:b4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4204000-b4204fff memory:b4200000-b4203fff
```

### `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` output

```
❯ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
--
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:108f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

### `iwlist scan` output

```
❯ iwlist scan
enp4s0f1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0    Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: E8:94:F6:A1:F2:04
                Channel:10
                Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-21 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"unknown"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000eaecc41c9
                Extra: Last beacon: 59956ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0007756E6B6E6F776E
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 03010A
                IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF1103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                IE: Unknown: 331AEF1103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                IE: Unknown: 3D160A0F0600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 34160A0F0600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101090003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD990050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D57523834314E10240003382E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57523834314E100800020086103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

### kernel version

```
❯ uname -r
4.8.0-58-generic
```

Please let me know if you need more information to solve this issue.

### UPDATE

Here are the last couple of lines from `syslog` (`kern.log` has pretty much the same info). I don't know what to search for, although there are only `<info>` statements and no `warn` or `error`. I've enabled/disabled networking a couple of times so the log should show it, however, in the period when these logs were taken, internet wasn't working (although laptop was connected to wifi):

```
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3511] manager: disable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3511] manager: disabling...
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3511] device (enp4s0f1): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3816] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3817] audit: op="networking-control" arg="off" pid=3479 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3820] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping') [100 110 37]
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:28] offline
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.3955] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping') [110 30 37]
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Withdrawing address record for xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx on wlp3s0.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.4282] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 14578
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.4282] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7889.696112] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.110 on wlp3s0.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.4290] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.110.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832368.4383] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop dbus[848]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop dnsmasq[2744]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: p2p-dev-wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop dbus[848]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 30 17:19:28 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832373.3065] manager: enable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: no)
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832373.3065] manager: re-enabling...
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832373.3065] device (enp4s0f1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.571194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f1: link is not ready
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832373.3316] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.595589] r8169 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: link down
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.595653] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0f1: link is not ready
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.596280] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.596564] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00ea
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.596591] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00ea(Receiver ID)
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.596594] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2:   device [8086:9d1a] error status/mask=00000081/00002000
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.596595] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.596596] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2:    [ 7] Bad DLLP              
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.629933] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00ea
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.629999] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00ea(Receiver ID)
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630060] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2:   device [8086:9d1a] error status/mask=00002041/00002000
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630061] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630062] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2:    [ 6] Bad TLP               
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630125] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00ea
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630189] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: can't find device of ID00ea
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630189] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: AER: Corrected error received: id=00ea
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7894.630252] pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: can't find device of ID00ea
Jun 30 17:19:33 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:33] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7896.519668] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832375.2533] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832375.2534] audit: op="networking-control" arg="on" pid=3479 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:35] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3s0 flags: No such device
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832375.3014] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832375.3015] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7896.568882] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7896.621363] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7896.827350] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
Jun 30 17:19:35 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7896.878873] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7141] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7272] policy: auto-activating connection 'unknown'
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7313] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'unknown' (69ed972a-7661-4c95-9261-53bbb1ff8306)
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7339] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7340] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7343] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7345] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'unknown' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7345] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7375] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7378] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7379] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'unknown' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7380] Config: added 'ssid' value 'unknown'
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7380] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7380] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7380] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7380] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Jun 30 17:19:39 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832379.7473] sup-iface[0xe1cd90,wlp3s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jun 30 17:19:40 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7901.555446] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (SSID='unknown' freq=2457 MHz)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.403805] wlp3s0: authenticate with AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1559] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.434249] wlp3s0: send auth to AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (try 1/3)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (SSID='unknown' freq=2457 MHz)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.437066] wlp3s0: authenticated
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1646] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.440273] wlp3s0: associate with AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (try 1/3)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.444215] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: wlp3s0: Associated with AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.446041] wlp3s0: associated
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.446087] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448157] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448157] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448158] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448158] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448159] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448159] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop kernel: [ 7905.448159] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: p2p-dev-wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1722] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop wpa_supplicant[1589]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1778] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1778] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'unknown'.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1779] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1782] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.1793] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 14888
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dhclient[14888]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.110 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x17522942)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dhclient[14888]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.110 from 192.168.0.1
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106]   address 192.168.0.110
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106]   gateway 192.168.0.1
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106]   lease time 7200
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106]   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2106] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.110.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.110 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2205] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2211] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2213] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2216] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:44] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dhclient[14888]: bound to 192.168.0.110 -- renewal in 3117 seconds.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2515] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2516] policy: set 'unknown' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dnsmasq[2744]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2517] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dnsmasq[2744]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53(via wlp3s0)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop NetworkManager[910]: <info>  [1498832384.2653] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dbus[848]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:44] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:44] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:19:44] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop dbus[848]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jun 30 17:19:44 iulian-laptop gnome-session[2993]: (deja-dup-monitor:5836): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 274 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jun 30 17:19:46 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx.
Jun 30 17:19:46 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 30 17:19:46 iulian-laptop avahi-daemon[840]: Registering new address record for xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx on wlp3s0.*.
Jun 30 17:20:04 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:20:04] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 30 17:20:24 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:20:24] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 30 17:20:44 iulian-laptop whoopsie[932]: [17:20:44] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jun 30 17:21:46 iulian-laptop pulseaudio[3111]: [pulseaudio] shm.c: shm_open() failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you see any logs in syslog and kern.log nything related to trouble related to network/devices

Comment: atheros is a little buggy, it is possible you need different driver than the repo generics. atheros, realtek and broadcom wireless card are often tweaked by the computer manufacturer so the precompiled driver supplied by ubuntu don't quite work right

Comment: @ravery Please don't write about things you have no idea about.

Comment: @ravery, I've updated my driver to the latest version when this problem appeared for the first time, but nothing changed

Comment: @Pilot- I know. I have had this problem with every computer I put ubuntu on.  Ubuntu themselves even say wifi cards  are a difficulty

Comment: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k  try these

Comment: @ravery How are the drivers you linked any different from that found in the default 4.8.0-xx kernel??

Comment: first they will be compiled to your kernel. second, who knows which drivers ubuntu used. they may have compiled out of date driver to the generic kernel of your version .... this was the case with the drivers for my wifi card (a realtek card). I ned drivers that weren't accepted into the repository yet

Comment: @ravery I don't think the original poster is well-served with "who knows" comments. If you don't know then why comment?

Comment: @chili555 -- the reply is not "who knows" if you read the entire post. do you know which drivers they used for their package???  probably not. the point is they don't always have up to date drivers. especially in the mainline repo. the site where i found my drivers is a year old and they still aren't included in mainline

Comment: @v_sukt most probably drivers are not the problem. please have a look at the update I have posted today.